# Coupled second order non linear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I solve two coupled non-linear second order ODE with following equation
$$
y_1'' = e^{-k_1(y_1-y_2)}-e^{-k_2(y_2-y_1)} \\ 
y_2'' = e^{-k_1(y_1-y_2)}-e^{-k_2(y_2-y_1)}
$$

Comment: Actually, they are linear (assuming $k_1,k_2$ are constants).  Also $y_1''=y_2''$ which will make things a lot easier.

Comment: They are coupled in terms of y1 and y2. I want an analytical solution for this. How can i proceed?

Answer (score 1):

As $y_1''=y_2''$ we get $y_1-y_2=ax+b$ and the differential equations reduce to
$$
y_1''=e^{-k_1(ax+b)}-e^{k_2(ax+b)}\\
y_2''=e^{-k_1(ax+b)}-e^{k_2(ax+b)}
$$
which can now easily be integrated twice.